# HDEL, HSET not working in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, hash, redis

can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
redis.hdel("hash:" + id + " key" function(err, success) {
    console.log("Hash Deleted");
});
```

Is there any other way to do it?

And I'm also struggling with HSET:

```
redis.hset("hash:" + id + " key", "true");
```

It tells me "wrong number of arguments". What more is it expecting? In the Redis documentation of HSET, there are no more parameters.

So I used HMSET instead, and it works properly. :)

Also, if anyone can tell me, some source where I can find examples of all commands or at least all the hash commands in NodeJS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`HSET` takes three parameters, `key`, `field`, `value`. `HDEL` takes two, `key` and `field`. Have you tried, [as per the readme](https://github.com/simplegeo/nodejs-redis#usage):

```
client.hset("key", "field", "value", callback);
```

Similarly,

```
client.hdel("key", "field", callback);
```

Comment: Although I figured it out just before u answered, thanks for clarifying the methods. :D